# Creating rest api from Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest

I have created models to save the product, categories and ProductCategory.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')                                  
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = '')

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer for the Model:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
        fields = '__all__'
```

ViewSets

```
class ProductViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductSerializer

class CategoryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer

class ProductCategoryViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.ProductCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductCategorySerializer
```

Until now I can add data to each table and view them from Django REST framework.

Json Response:

Product:

```
[
...
   {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Jacket One",
   }
...
]
```

Category

```
[
    ...
       {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Jacket",
       }
    ...
    ]
```

Product Category

```
[
    ...
       {
          "id": 1,
          "product": 1,
        "category": 1
       }
    ...
    ]
```

The actual json I want to create is:

```
[
    "jacket":[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Jacket One",
       }
       ......other jacket products......
     ],

    ........ other categories with their products ............

]
```

How could I achieve such json. I tried joining the models and filtering in the queryset but could not figure it out. Any help in the correct direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use ```rest_framework``` in serializers. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: I have used serializer. What I am asking is how to join two models using a pivot table and then creating json response on top of it. Thank you for your response.